# Dans l´attente + ant?

Tags: sens, traduction, usage

Bonsoir,

je me suis souvent demandé s´il y a une règle qui dit qu´on est obligé de construire une phrase avec une seule forme en "-ant" ? C'est à dire, est-ce qu'une règle interdirait de coordonner plusieurs participes présent ?

Parlant l´anglais, j´ai une maîtrise...
⟾
Parlant l´anglais et maîtrisant...

Est-ce qu'une des phrases est fausse ?

Sinon, quelle est la structure la plus naturelle ?

De plus, si on commençait avec "dans l´attente", pourrait-on continuer avec une forme en "-ant" ?

Dans l´attente de te lire, je te souhaite une bonne journée.

ou

Dans l´attente de te lire et te souhaitant une bonne journée,

Toute correction sera très appréciée.

Answer (score 2):

1. Est-ce qu'une des phrases est fausse ?

   À priori non, mais les deux phrases étant incomplètes, on ne peut pas non plus affirmer qu'elles sont correctes.
2. Sinon, quelle est la structure la plus naturelle ?

   Les deux sont naturelles, mais seulement à l'écrit car le participe présent est très rare à l'oral sauf quand il s'agit d'un gérondif, c'est à dire précédé de *en*.
3. De plus, si on commençait avec "dans l´attente", pourrait-on continuer avec une forme en "‑ant" ?

   Oui, telles que présentées, les deux formes sont correctes.

Comment: J´ai juste lu et voudrais vous remercie.

Answer (score 0):

**I** « Parlant l´anglais, j´ai une maîtrise » ne va pas parce que ce qui suit la proposition participiale doit être compris comme en partie expliqué par ce que cette proposition exprime.

- Parlant l'anglais, j'ai pu expliquer à ces touristes comment se rendre à la gare.
  (*As I speak English, I could explain to those tourists how to go to the train station.*)
- Parlant bien l'anglais, je n'aurai pas de difficulté à trouver un travail de secrétaire.
- Parlant l'anglais, elle a la possibilité de vérifier les traductions de ses romans favoris en lisant l'original anglais.

« Dans l'attente » n'a rien à voir avec la construction expliquée ci-dessus. C'est une formule de conclusion, par exemple dans une lettre.

Il faut savoir que dans le parler de tous les jours cette tournure n'est pas très utilisée mais elle convient bien dans la langue écrite.
Vous pouvez utiliser deux et même trois participes présent coordonnés, mais le principe expliqué ci-dessus est alors applicable à tous.

- Aujourd'hui, *ayant fini* ma journée plus tôt et n'*ayant* plus *à envoyer* mes enfants à l'école, j'ai eu toute une après-midi pour lire.

---

**II** *Dans l´attente de te lire, je te souhaite une bonne journée.*
   *Dans l´attente de te lire et te souhaitant une bonne journée,*

Les deux phrases sont correctes; plus précisément la première est correcte et le début de la seconde aussi à condition qu'il n'y ait pas d'erreur et qu'il s'agisse bien d'une virgule à la fin, cela signifiant qu'il y a une continuation et une continuation est nécessaire ;  remplacer la virgule par un point final fais de ce bout de phrase une phrase incorrecte.

Comment: Merci beaucoup de cette bonne explication! C´est devenu tellement plus claire.

Comment: @Hanna Pas d'e à la fin de«  clair » ; il s'agit du genre neutre parce que « c' », qui est la forme élidée de « ce », est un pronom neutre.

Comment: Tu as bien mis en lumière qu´il faut répéter, j´ai presque oubliée qu´il y a un neutre. Merci pour avoir relis et corrigé.

Comment: « mettre en lumière » ne se dit pas pour traduire « to hightlight »  dans ce cas ((TLFi) Mettre en lumière. Élucider.); « souligner ».  j´ai presque oublié qu´il y a un neutre. Merci pour avoir relu et corrigé.

Comment: merci LPH, c´était très gentil de répondre à mes questions.